# Value that related with both chekcbox and radio button

Tags: spring, jsp

My jsp page where if check a radio button it shows a checkbox.

At present when i click on chekckbox and submit it gets value : 
"GRAD,PPG" for the field 'degree'.

My JSP code :

```
    <spring:bind path="degree"> 
         <div> 
            <form:radiobutton path="degree" id="degree" value="GRAD" required="true" data-id="g"/>   Graduate                             
               <div id="mppg-program">
                  <form:checkbox path="degree" id="mppg-checkbox" 
                  value="PPG"/> MPPG Program
               </div>
    </spring:bind>
```

I want to fix it like this way :

- When it is checked value : 'PPG'
- When it is uncheked value : 'GRAD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using javascript while submitting the form.

JSP:

```
<spring:bind path="degree"> 
       <div>
        <input type="radio" name="degreeGrad" value="GRAD"> Graduate<br> 
        <div id="mppg-program">
            <input type="checkbox" name="degreePPG" value="PPG">MPPG Program
        </div>
        <form:hidden path="degree" />
 </spring:bind>
```

While submitting the form , the appropriate value can be assigned to `degree` based on the  condition as below

JavaScript:

```
function submitForm(){
  if(document.yourform.degreeGrad.checked){
     document.yourform.degree.value=document.yourform.degreeGrad.value;
  }else if(document.yourform.degreePPG.checked){
     document.yourform.degree.value=document.yourform.degreePPG.value;
  }else{//default value if required
    document.yourform.degree.value='<default value>'
  }
  document.yourform.submit();
}
```